# Are restaurants forced to call the cops if a customer enters a restaurant without a vaccine passport in Quebec?

Tags: criminal-law, quebec

Are restaurants forced to call the cops if a customer enters a restaurant without a vaccine passport in Quebec? I heard a vaccine passport was implemented in Quebec and I was wondering if restaurants are held criminally liable if they adopt a vaccine passport rule, but they don't decide to call the cops and kick a client out of a restaurant even though he refused to provide one and sat inside of the restaurant for a prolonged period of time, also what if they decided to serve the man after a while? I am thinking as long as they don't serve him, it's fine, but as soon as they serve him they would be held criminally liable.

Comment: I doubt this would be a "criminal" liability, more of a civil one. It only crosses into criminal territory when there is a falsification of records or altering an official document.

Comment: This should be easy to answer from the actual text of the legislation or order, but I'm having trouble finding it.  Anyone else have any luck?  (@Sayaman, did you try to find it?)

Comment: I tried to google it, but couldn't think of a way to get the actual result of the question since the keyword I used didn't match any relevant result.

Comment: Also, the government's website doesn't really go into detail about the law itself.

Comment: They are probably not forced to call the cops, but to prevent the customer from entering or to remove him from the premises. And if the customer tries to force his entry or refuses to leave, he will be trespassing and then calling the cops is the appropiate measure for removing him.